# How to export the contents of a combo box to the datatable?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I want to export the contents of a combo box to the local data table so that I can parametrize the test using that value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get each item from the ComboBox. For example where `Window Name` and `ComboBox Name` are the names of your window and ComboBox respectively

```
comboBox = Window("Window Name").WinComboBox("ComboBox Name");
count = comboBox.GetItemsCount
For i = 0 to count-1 
  item = comboBox.GetItem(i) 
  ' put the item in the DataTable...
Next
```

How you output each item, the `' put the item in the DataTable..` line, will depend on your set up.